# Visual Studio - Changing DEBUG port on Solution not WebSite

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I am encountering problems, where when debugging, it's using a port that I dont want it to use.

I understand that in Visual Studio, when debugging a 'web site', you can change the port used in the properties window of the project.

However, where can I specify the port used on a solution/project, since the option isn't available in the properties window for the solution OR the project?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it's preventing me from debugging a particular solution.

Comment: Regular project / solution don't have PORT property for obvious reason - it doesn't need one. Could you clarify what kind of port do you need to change ? Website is specifying port to host IIS server. Projects/solutions do not host IIS server upon startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the port where the VS Development Server runs your project then you can find that in the project `Properties` -> `Web section` -> `Servers` -> `Use Visual Studio Development Server`, `Specific Port`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Click on your application in the solution manager

2) View -> Property Pages

3) Select the 'Web' tab on the left

4) Set 'Start Action' to a specific page.